# How to set custom admin login URL in Django Admin on session timeout?

Tags: django, authentication

I wrote a Django app which has an external authentication system reacheable at some URL (say, `https://.../myproject/login`). This is working well.

However, when the session expires, the user gets redirected to the default login url which is `https://.../myproject/admin`). I'd like to change the behavior of the app so if the session expires, the user should be redirected to `https://.../myproject/login` and only use the `/admin` login when explicitly opened.

Is there a built-in way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#login-url

Redirect to `myproject/login` for login (Default redirects to /accounts/login/)

```
LOGIN_URL = '/myproject/login/'
```

Redirect to the login page after log out (Default to None).

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/myproject/login/'
```

Answer (score 6):

Django admin redirects the users to /admin/login when the session is expired or session is missing.

There are several ways to redirect users to https://.../myproject/login instead of https://.../myproject/admin/login.

#### Approach 1:

Override the view of myproject/admin/login URL with the view of myproject/login.

Let's say that myproject/login uses LoginView to render external system's login page, then add `url(r'^admin/login/?$', LoginView.as_view(), name='admin:login')` just above `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))` in myproject/myproject/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/login/?$', LoginView.as_view(), name='admin:login'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Pros:

- Render the external system's login page instead of default Django admin login page on /myproject/admin/login

Cons:

- The URL still points to myproject/admin/login
- No way to access the default admin login page

#### Approach 2:

Override the view of myproject/admin/login url and redirect the user to myproject/login

Lets create a new view `AdminLoginView` then add url(r'^admin/login/?$', AdminLoginView.as_view(), name='admin:login') just above url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) in myproject/myproject/urls.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class AdminLoginView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Assuming the name of the external system's login url is "login"
        """
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
```

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/login/?$', AdminLoginView.as_view(), name='admin:login'),
   url(r'^admin/default-login/?$', admin.site.login, name='default-admin-login'),
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Pros:

- The URL changes to myproject/login

Cons:

- You have to add extra code for the default login page.

I would recommend approach 2 to solve the problem mentioned in the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best possible solution is to **override** the function for login view.

To do this **add these lines** of code in your **urls.py** containing the 'admin/'

```py
# urls.py

def login(request):
   if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index', current_app='admin'))
   else:
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index', current_app='your_app_name'))


admin.site.login = login


# The lines below probably exist

# urlpatterns = [
# path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
# path('', include('your_app.urls')),
# ]
```